# Record is not getting inserted properly into ms access database using javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-access

I am trying to insert a record into access database, and below code is working (Its inserting the data into the database.) but the data is not being inserted after the very last record, its getting inserted after some rows from the last record.
Could someone suggest me, how to insert the new record just after the last existing one.
The table sheet1 is having two fields "SNO" and "Name".

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function AddRecord() {
  var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

  adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='F:\\insert.mdb'");
  adoRS.Open("Select * From sheet1", adoConn, 1, 3);
  adoRS.AddNew;
  adoRS.Fields("SNO").value = "1";
  adoRS.Fields("Name").value = "Someone";
  adoRS.Update;

  adoRS.Close();
  adoConn.Close();
}
</script>

<html>
<body>
<input name="button" type="button" onClick="AddRecord()" value="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your table is autoincrement?

Comment: No, No column is autoincrement.

Comment: What do you mean by "after some rows from the last record"? The last record is the last one in the list, how can there be "some rows" after that?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu : Thanks for the comment.
But if you see the record after opening the access database in table view, there are some blank line between the last existing record and the Latest inserted one by the code.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento : Thank for the comment, No the record is being inserted as it is, but if you see the record after opening the access database in table view, there are some blank line between the last existing record and the Latest inserted one by the code.

Comment: @user3103991 post structure of mdb.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento : Hi the table sheet1 is having two fields "SNO" and "Name", and the table already have some data into it. Could you please suggest how the insert into can be use in place of addNew.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento                                                Field Name         Data type                                              SNO                Number                                                        Name               Text

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: I really appreciate your suggestions, I think i was using a Excel sheet Linked table, and that may be causing that problem.
coz when i created a table normally, that worked.
thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be a bug in ADO in which you had to move the record pointer before it was flushed to disk.  Try adding this line.

```
  -- Ad line after update
  adoRS.MoveNext;
```

Also, are you working with an MS Excel workbook?  The [sheet1] name is kinda a give away.

I recreated you environment less the linked in MS Excel spreadsheet.

It works fine for me.  Even with the .MoveNext() code.

Ditch the linked in Excel sheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ya the table is a linked table with some excel sheet

Comment: Could you please try by adding some record first into the database and then try to add the data using the script.

Comment: Manually adding data by hand should not matter.  Added 4 records by hand and three records by ASP program ...

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

**I believe this:**

1- Or you posted a code that is not what is causing the failure and its original code has some "autorun" (loading the page the "insert function" is called) that is sending empty values​​.

2- Or the structure of your *.MDB* is some problem.

> Note: I know what are the columns, but sometimes you did something
>   wrong, some attribute you setou (perhaps automatically)

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions, I i believe i was using a Excel sheet Linked table, and that may be causing that problem. coz when i created a table normally, that worked. thanks again. :)

Comment: When you have a doubt is better by a code that you have tested and verified that the fault is occurring, and put all the details and thoroughly (review the written text). This is only a tip in order to help you get better answers. You use googleplus or other messenger?

Comment: Yes GooglePlus.. and facebook.. :)

Comment: I did mention to drop the excel linked table?